# Limit of sum of factions of finite constants and matrix

Tags: limits, vectors, positive-semidefinite

Suppose $\mathbf{a}_{i}$ is a $2\times 1$ constant vector with $\frac{1}{N}%
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\mathbf{a}_{i}\mathbf{a}_{i}^{T}$ converges to a finite $%
2\times 2$ matrix as $N\rightarrow \infty $, and $b_{i}$ is a finite positive
constant with $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}b_{i}$ converges to a finite constant as $%
N\rightarrow \infty $, then what is the limit of the following form
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{\mathbf{a}_{i}\mathbf{a}_{i}^{T}}{\mathbf{a}%
_{i}^{T}\mathbf{a}_{i}+b_{i}}, 
\end{equation}
as $N\rightarrow \infty ,$ does it have a close form? Thanks